# I'm making an AJAX request and sending param to servlet. I can see parameter in the url but i'm not able to get the request parameter in the servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

This is my jquery code

```
//jquery
<script>
$.post("dashboardcon", $("#date").serialize(), function(responseHtml) {
    $('#date').html(responseHtml); 
});
</script>
```

html

```
<form>
    Date :<br> <input id="date" type="text" name="date">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

servlet

```
@WebServlet("/dashboardcon")
public class dashboardCon extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject newObj = jObj.getJSONObject(request.getParameter("date"));
            System.out.println(newObj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're sending to the correct URL of your servlet?

Comment: yes! I checked it

Comment: What is the back end language and how are you checking for the parameter there?

Comment: You should edit your title...

Comment: You are using ajax request to sending form data of jquery Post method. You should use $.post( "dashboardcon", { date: $("#date").val()},funcion..

Answer (score 0):

You must have something like this on your servlet:

```
 JSONObject jObj    = new JSONObject();
 JSONObject newObj = jObj.getJSONObject(request.getParameter("date"));
```

Whichi i cant see in your code.

Comment: now I'm is getting this error "org.json.JSONException: Null key.
null...."

Comment: if you don't post your code i can't do anything by guessinh that! You must help us for helping you! Thats the way it goes.

Comment: I'm sorry! I added servlet code also